# Java ClassVersionError although version seems to be okay

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, tomcat7

I'm getting the following error in my java web app (The application launches okay but when I click a button following error occurs). I'm using Tomcat (7.0.109) to run this application. 
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: FileDetailsServlet has been compiled by a more recent 
 version of the Java Runtime (class file version 59.0), this version of the Java Runtime only 
 recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 (unable to load class [FileDetailsServlet])

Previously I used Java 15 (class version 59.0). But then I switched to JDK and JRE 1.8.0_311 (class version upto 52.0)because of other 3rd party apps.

Here are some things that I did

1. I've checked class version of **FileDetailsServlet** class using this
   `javap -verbose FileDetailsServlet| findstr "major"`
   command. And it shows that version is 51.0 (Java 7).
2. I've set JDK compliance to 1.8 in eclipse. (Project specific settings)
3. After changing JDK I recompiled all the files using JDK 1.8.0_311
4. I've checked environment variables. JAVA_HOME is "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311"
   JRE_HOME is "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_311" and Path is "C:\Program
   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_311\bin"

Am I missing anything? I can not go back to Java 15. So is there any way around?

Comment: Does the order of the list reflect the order in which you performed the actions? It looks suspicious if your files show version 51.0 after you compiled them with JDK 1.8.0, also after you compiled them with Java 15. Did you specify a target version for the compiler by some means?

Comment: The order of the list doesn't reflect the order of my actions. When I was using Java 15 I set the jdk compliance to JavaSE 1.7 (I was told to do so)

Comment: If you set the target version to 1.7 and the setting would have worked for the deployment, the above UnsupportedClassVersionError should not have happened at all. Very strange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your class path for any "leftovers" from the old system. It looks like you are not inspecting the correct files. Maybe you have the FileDetailsServlet in a wrong version as depencency somewhere, or just in a "standalone" JAR- or WAR-file.

It is also important that Eclipse settings alone will maybe not cover, how the used container serves the servlet, so which technology do you use to run the FileDetailsServlet? That's the crucial point: this thing that you use to run (Tomcat, Jetty, other container, maybe included in a fat WAR or fat JAR file from Sprint Boot or another similar technology) has to use the correct *.class* file.

As you are using Tomcat as container:
You should check the class files inside the folder *webapps/appname* folder below your tomcat folder (replace appname with the deployment context name) Take care: when you run tomcat from Eclipse this could be somewhere completely different than the installation folder on disk, but I don't have an Eclipse installation ready to check that.

Comment: I'm using tomcat to run this web app. How to check which .class file is tomcat using? I'm new in this so not sure where to check.

Comment: Please update your question (for others when they search for answers later on) with that information. And consider adding "tomcat" as a tag please.

Comment: Search the Tomcat directory tree.  The most likely places are in your webapp's /WEB-INF/classes/ or /WEB-INF/lib or in the shared library directory: $CATALINA_HOME/lib.  See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/deployment.html for more info.