# Eclipse not updating .class files

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a java web application. Previously I compiled all .java files with JDK 15. But because of some 3rd party apps I had to switch to JDK1.8. Now the problem is when I build the project .class files are not updated. I have checked the version with `javap -verbose ClassName.class | findstr "major"` command. Class version is still 59.0. I have already tried steps in this link [Why isn't Eclipse updating the classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573416/why-isnt-eclipse-updating-the-classes). I have also checked **JAVA_HOME** and **Path** variable. These are set to JDK1.8 And here are other configurations in eclipse

1. **JRE System Library** is jre1.8
2. Project -> Properties -> Builders, **Java Builder** is checked
3. Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export **JRE System Library** is checked
4. Checked **.project** file

```
<buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
</natures>
```

above configurations are present. 
Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: "Use default compliance settings" is checked. "Generated .class files compatibility" is 1.8. "Source Compatibility" is 1.8

Comment: You have [already asked that question four days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71253112/6505250) and accepted an answer. What's the purpose to ask it again?

Comment: Initially I was having problem with tomcat. I fixed that issue by copying correct version of .class files in the webapps directory. But it is not meant to be done manually. So I need to figure out why compiling with eclipse is not updating the .class files.

Comment: Make sure in _Properties > Project: Java Build Path_ tab _Source_ the correct output folder(s) are configured.

Comment: That was the issue. The default output folder was set to some directory like **ProjectName/bin** and I was looking into some other directory like **ProjectName/classes/packages**. The class files at the output folder had the correct class version (52) as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure in ***Properties > Project: Java Build Path*** tab ***Source*** the correct **output folder**(s) are configured.